# How do I exit Qpython (android) console automatically afer script completes?

Tags: android, console, qpython

I'm running Qpython (andoid) 1.2.3 (the latest as of 2016-01-31) and I can get scripts to run. I've been able to create a shortcut on my homescreen for a simple test script that put the current date in yyyy-mm-dd format into the clipboard, and speaks the content. I have #qpy: console directing the script to execure in the console. When I click the shortcut, the clipboard is happily updated, and read out to me. But... the console window stays open, telling me to hit enter to close the window.

I have tried:

- adding "exit"
- adding "exit(0)"
- adding 

  import sys

  sys.exit()
- I have tried printing ctrl-d

I still get the console staying open until I manually hit enter.

I tried reheadering my script to run as kivy instead of console, and I could get it to exit, but it takes several seconds to load up kivy, and it's silly to load a huge amount of gui capability, when I neither need nor want them.

How can I close the console automatically?

Comment: Forgot to mention this is on a Samsung Tab 2 running android 4.2.2, _NOT_ rooted.

Comment: I also have this problem. did you find a solution?

Comment: I have also this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you upgrade to the newest version ?
And it support Q mode, just insert "#qpy:qpyapp" into your script.

http://www.qpython.org/en/guide_program.html (In the end of the page)

Answer (score 0):

edit the file end.sh. Remove or comment the "read" command.